# Unable to click on span using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium

Here is my code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('driver/path')
driver.get('http://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g51867-d616623-Reviews-or50-Park_Motel-Florence_Oregon.html#REVIEWS')
mores = driver.find_element_by_class_name('moreLink')
mores.click()
```

I get this exception:

```
Element is not clickable at point (220, 701). Other element would receive the click: <div class="prw_rup prw_prodp13n_recommendation_carousels_related_footer_xsell" data-prwidget-name="prodp13n_recommendation_carousels_related_footer_xsell" data-prwidget-init="handlers">...</div>
(Session info: chrome=47.0.2526.106)
```

I tried anything  I found on web to fix it, but I failed. Here are things I tried:

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(mores).click().perform()
```

(no exception, but still no click)

```
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)', mores)
mores.click()
```

(same exception having different coordinates)

It is very strange, since when I scroll the page manually to the same position that the script scrolls, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Ah!, I do not see any `web element` with `class-name` **moreLink** that is **clickable**- If nothing works then you can use below process (kind of a bruit-force). It is suggested to use better way to solve this problem.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g51867-d616623-Reviews-or50-Park_Motel-Florence_Oregon.html#REVIEWS')
bd = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
for i in range(5000): #5000 is just a high value to ensure longer press
    bd.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
driver.quit()
```